# How to add a value to every element in a specified column of a 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a matrix, `a`:

```
a = np.random.randn(10,7)
a = a.astype(int)
```

How do I add 2 to every element in a specified column, let's say column 3?

I have tried a few approaches such as `result = [x+2 for x in a]` , but that doesn't work for 2D arrays because I don't know how to specify a column, and `result = np.add(a(:,3(i+2)))` which obviously gives me invalid syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: See the indexing reference that I linked in your previous question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = np.random.randn(10, 7)
a = a.astype(int)
print(a)
a[:, 2] += 2
print(a)
```